# Xamarin in app billing plugin doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am having problem with xamarin in app billing plugin. I used almost the same code which James Montemagno writes in his blog in this article => https://blog.xamarin.com/integrating-in-app-purchases-in-mobile-apps/

I tried lots of things but PurchaseAsync method always returns null. Any idea how to fix this ? Thank you in advance.

```
       private  async void Btn_ClickAsync(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioGroup radioGroup = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.radioGroup1);
        RadioButton radioButton = FindViewById<RadioButton>(radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId);


        string selectedproduct =  radioButton.Tag.ToString();
        string a = editText1.Text, b = editText2.Text;
        try
        {
            var productId = selectedproduct;
            var connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();
            if (!connected)
            {
                //Couldn't connect to billing, could be offline, alert user

                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
       .SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender2, args) =>{})
       .SetMessage("Couldn't connect to billing,")
       .SetTitle("Error")
       .Show();
                return;
            }

            //try to purchase item
            var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase,"apppayload");

            if (purchase == null)
            {
           //Not purchased, alert the user
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender2, args) =>{ })
            .SetMessage("Not purchased")
            .SetTitle("Error")
            .Show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //Purchased, save this information
                var id = purchase.Id;
                var token = purchase.PurchaseToken;
                var state = purchase.State;
            }
        }
        catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
        {
           Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, purchaseEx.InnerException.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Disconnect, it is okay if we never connected
           await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        InAppBillingImplementation.HandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow James Montemagno's guide with precision.

https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/GettingStarted.html

I've been through the entire experience of implementing this using Xamarin and his library. When configured properly, everything works.

I definitely missed a few things near the bottom of the getting started guide for android and this stumped me for a while.

A few things I discovered on my own:

1. The bundle identifier in info.plist must match the itunesconnect bundle id in order to see a listing of products on the ios simulator
2. Test purchases, which let your selected license-test users purchase your in-app products without any resulting charges to the user. Test purchases can be used in alpha/beta releases only. Google will charge regular users even though the app is in alpha.

Answer (score -1):

Update your alpha apk file and try again. You have to use Play Store version of your app. Debugging in-app purchases are painful.